# Target file "macos" not found

Tags: ios, macos, flutter

I can successfully build an iOS app with

```
flutter build ios
```

But when I try to turn the app in macOS using

```
flutter run macos
```

I get this error

> Target file "macos" not found.

Although I have `macos` directory in my project root. But still I'm unable to run the app in macOS.

---

#### Update

After deleting macos folder and running `flutter create .`

> Recreating project ....
> macos/Runner.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
> macos/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_16.png (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_1024.png (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_256.png (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_64.png (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_512.png (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_128.png (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json (created)
> macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/app_icon_32.png (created)
> macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements (created)
> macos/Runner/Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib (created)
> macos/Runner/MainFlutterWindow.swift (created)
> macos/Runner/Configs/Debug.xcconfig (created)
> macos/Runner/Configs/Release.xcconfig (created)
> macos/Runner/Configs/Warnings.xcconfig (created)
> macos/Runner/Configs/AppInfo.xcconfig (created)
> macos/Runner/AppDelegate.swift (created)
> macos/Runner/Info.plist (created)
> macos/Runner/Release.entitlements (created)
> macos/Runner.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist (created)
> macos/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj (created)
> macos/Runner.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/Runner.xcscheme (created)
> macos/Flutter/Flutter-Debug.xcconfig (created)
> macos/Flutter/Flutter-Release.xcconfig (created)
> macos/.gitignore (created)
> Running "flutter pub get" in practice...                         2,611ms
> Wrote 29 files.

> All done!
> In order to run your application, type:
> $ cd .
> $ flutter run
> Your application code is in ./lib/main.dart.

And now if I run `flutter run macos`, it again gives me the same error:

> Target file "macos" not found.

#### Update-2

I just ran `flutter build macos` and found that there are some errors in particular to macos. I think I need to resolve them first in order to make the app run in macos.

Comment: do you have flutter-specific files inside this target?

Comment: @mightybruno I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: If you didn't touch the files in the macos folder, did you consider removing this folder and running again the `flutter create .` method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a param in your command.
Run `flutter run -d macos` and it should work smoothly :)

Comment: HI, thanks for your input. I just realized there's an error in my project (only for macos), when I run `flutter build ios`, it builds. But I just did `flutter build macos` and I started seeing some error which I believe is the root cause of not making the app run in macos. Although the error is completely different but I think this could be an isue.

Comment: At least your initial problem is fixed with the "-d" param you were missing ! GL Fixing your project :)

Comment: When I run the app using the command you showed, the console did show the error. So, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: This command is the one used to generate a release build

Comment: My bad haha. I meant is `flutter run macos` isn't essentially a `flutter run -d macos`.

Answer (score 2):

delete `macos` and then run `flutter create .` inside your project root, it will generate missing targets without touching existing ones

Comment: I already tried this command before posting the question.

Comment: sorry for misleading you, but you're right. You'd have to replace `temp` with your project name. I've tried running the command I've posted above and it created only missing targets

Comment: have you enabled desktop target? `flutter config --enable-macos-desktop`

Comment: I deleted the macos folder, ran the `flutter create .` it does show creation of files in the terminal but when I run the app, it again gives me the same error. Let me try `flutter config...` command now

Comment: does it actually create `macos` folder? if not, try to run the command with `config` and rerun `create`

Comment: I'll upvote your post for sure, because now my app is up and running. I think config also played some role (although the main issue were the errors).

Answer (score 0):

please check your flutter channel. I've switched to master with this command and it works :

flutter channel master

then :
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop

you might need to also do after the command above:

flutter create .

then :

flutter build macos